# Exporting data from essbase through FDMEE

Tags: mdx, hyperion, essbase

The main objective is to extract data from essbase through FDMEE.

i have written a script called extract_data.scr and placed it in the FDMEE server.

**extract_data.scr:**

```
spool on to "G:\\LOGFILE_$3.log";

set column_width 200;

/* to make spool file cleaner, return only warnings */

set message level warning;

set column_separator ~;

set column_header off;

set echo_mode off;

login $1 identified by $2 on $4;
spool on to "G:\\output.csv";

SELECT

Crossjoin(

{[Z1],[Z2],[Z3]},

{[M1]}) ON COLUMNS,

{[X1],[X2],[X3]} ON ROWS

FROM [CUBE]

WHERE [CONDITIONS];
 
spool off;
logout;
exit;
```

i can trigger the above script from cmd using below:

```
essmsh G:\extract_data.scr.scr test_user pass12343 CUBE ESSBASE_HOST
```

the above runs perfectly and spools the essbase ouput to a csv file. but i need to execute the same script through FDMEE.